# For which values of $m$ the line is tangent to the quadratic curve?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line, slope

For which values of $m$, the line $y=2x-4$ is tangent to the curve $y=(m+3)x^2+mx ?$

We have a quadratic equation. the equation of slope of tangent line to it for specific $x$ can be find by $y'=(2m+6)x+m$. but when I compare it to $y=2x-4$, I can't find $m$.

Comment: Note that $y'$ just gives the slope of the line not the equation ,so you have to find the intersecting point,better would be to sub $y=2x-4$ to the given and set the discriminant=0

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Oh you are right. I missed that.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I know to find the common point of the line and the curve we should equate them. so after equating them, we put discriminant equal to zero in order to have only one intersection point (because they are tangent). am I right?

Comment: yes !you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after a point $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$ such that:

- $(a,b)$ belongs to the curve $y=(m+3)x^2+mx$;
- $(a,b)$ belongs to the line $y=2x-4$;
- the slope of $y$ at $(a,b)$ is equal to $2$.

This means that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}b=(m+3)a^2+ma\\b=2a-4\\(2m+6)a+m=2\end{array}\right.$$There are only two solutions: $m=-2$ (in which case $a=2$ and $b=0$) and $m=22$ (in which case $a=-\frac25$ and $b=-\frac{24}5$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think there is a typo in the second line.I think you meant $(a,b)$ belongs to curve.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$m$ can be found without using slope. The given line touches the curve at $(x,2x-4)$ so that
$$2x-4=(m+3)x^2+mx$$
is satisfied.  This is a quadratic in $x$,
$$(m+3)x^2+(m-2)x+4=0$$
and its discriminant is zero, since for a given $m$, the quadratic has a unique root (tangency point). Thus
$$D : (m-2)^2-4\cdot 4 \cdot (m+3)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow m^2-20m-44=0 \Rightarrow m=22,-2$$